# Elasticsearch 1.3.8 transform with groovy script file

Tags: elasticsearch

Due to a security vulnerability with ES 1.3.4 we upgraded to ES 1.3.9 which disabled dynamic groovy scripting, as a result the mapping transformations are failing with the error message "dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled". I tried the approach in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/modules-scripting.html by externalizing the script to a script file but the script file is not getting invoked or the transformation is not working. How can we achieve the transformation using a script file

Mapping file transform is as follows:

```
"transform" : [{
      "script" : "ctx._source['downloadCountInt'] = (ctx._source['downloadCount']==null)? ctx._source['downloadCount'] : ctx._source['downloadCount'].replaceAll(/\\D/, '');",
      "lang" : "groovy"
    }]
```

Tried putting the script `ctx._source['downloadCountInt'] = (ctx._source['downloadCount']==null)? ctx._source['downloadCount'] : ctx._source['downloadCount'].replaceAll(/\\D/, '');` into a script file named "transform_download_count.groovy" in /etc/elasticsearch/scripts/transform_download_count.groovy and the log messages show that it was compiled correctly but the transformation is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

With the script file `/etc/elasticsearch/scripts/transform_download_count.groovy` in place try:

```
"transform" : {
  "script_file" : "transform_download_count",
  "lang" : "groovy"
}
```